# Displaying custom keyboard build with storyboard on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-storyboard

Okay, so I'm developing a custom keyboard for iOS in Xcode 7.1, and I've run into an issue...

Using the **NSExtensionPrincipalClass**, the out-of-the-box solution, works fine, but when I use a Storyboard and replace that entry in the plist with "NSExtensionMainStoryboard", it only works on the Simulator and not on a physical device... On a physical device, it just switches back to the previous keyboard when trying to select it...

In other SO posts, I've seen people say that setting `RequestsOpenAccess` to TRUE worked for them, but no luck here...

Below you can see my Extension entry in the `plist`...

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
  <string>Keyboard</string>
  <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
  <dict>
    <key>IsASCIICapable</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PrefersRightToLeft</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PrimaryLanguage</key>
    <string>en-US</string>
    <key>RequestsOpenAccess</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
  <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.keyboard-service</string>
</dict>
```

I haven't shared any of my remaining code, as it works on the Simulator, so I'm guessing it's some kind of settings issue or bug?

In Xcode, I can see the logs:

> plugin 'xxx' interrupted
>
> plugin 'xxx' invalidated

Any ideas on what I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue.. Have you resolved this issue or does `NSExtensionMainStoryboard` just not work for keyboard extensions?

Answer (score 2):

I just resolved the same issue by checking the `Is Initial View Controller` box in the attributes inspector of the view controller in the storyboard. This makes sense as the app will need to find the first VC to init when starting.

Image of check box:
[image]